# Android: ListView Trouble with textview.isChecked() and textview.setChecked()

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which uses this layout:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked
```

I have an OnItemClickListener that gets the check status of the clicked item and either checks or unchecks that item but it does not work. There are NO errors in logcat. When I click on an item in the listview simply nothing happens.

The OnItemClickListener looks like this:

```
//------------------- OnItemClickListener -----------------------------
    lvCheckList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)view;

                     if (!textview.isChecked()){
                         textview.setChecked(true);

                     }else {
                            textview.setChecked(false);

                     }
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this...**

//sample code

```
TextView TxtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameControlId);
TxtName.setOnClickListener(this);


@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.NameControlId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

}
```